# Automatic migration runs on a production server

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-identity

I have been developing my app in a Visual Studio 2013 on a notebook and finally I decided to put the code on server (Windows Server 2012) so I backed up my MS SQL db, restored it on a production server, copied my code, created a site and ended up with the following message:

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'MyUserInfoes' in the database.**

I use **ASP.NET Identity** and could not avoid using **Automatic Migration**. Anyway, I did set

```
    Public Sub New()
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = True
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = True
    End Sub
```

in **Configuration.vb** file but nothing changed.

The Automatic Migration insists on running on the production server and I cannot stop it. Any suggestions here, please? Thanks!

Comment: you sure you migrated over your migrationHistory table in your DB backup?

Comment: yes, I am, the table is there, full db backup and restore

Comment: Looks like the metadata in `__MigrationHistory` is out of sync with the actual DB Schema as it tries to add a table that's already in the DB. Do you have different default schemas for the users on the prod and dev server?

Comment: No, everything is the same on dev and prod systems except OS versions (Win 8.1, Win Server 2012). I tried to run "add-migration initial" plus "update-database" to get empty Up and Down methods but it did not help. Is there a chance to avoid migrations at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible issues include:**

1. Code copied uses a different Namespace or different type in context or migration class.
   and therefore no longer matches the record in [__MigrationHistory]
2. [__MigrationHistory] was no part of the backup and/or the restore

Comment: 1. The code has been copied 1:1 from source to destination.

Comment: 2. The _MigrationHistory table was included in the backup (all tables).